# Android Studio / IntelliJ better methods navigation in the structure tab

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation, android-studio, structure

Is there a way to organize methods in the structure tab view? The standard possibilties are "sort by visibility" and "sort alphabetically" but I need a little bit more. I would like to create lists or sections like "pragma mark" such as in XCode.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting down voted, I was looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.  The nearest I've come (and it doesn't help in the structure view) is to bracket sections of your code with `//region <name>` and `//endregion`

For example:

```
//region GETTERS AND SETTERS
public String getSomething() {
    return something
}
//endregion
```

When you click on the '-' icon next to the //region line, everything collapses and you are left with

```
GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

Nowhere near as nice as `#pragma mark`, but at least when editing your source you can hide most of the trees to see some wood :-)